# How do I get gsub() to replace my spaces with underscores rather than periods?

Tags: r

This is what I've been doing

```
data <- read.csv("path to csv", skip = 43)
gsub(' ', '_', data)
write.csv(data, "path to csv again", row.names = FALSE)
```

Things that I tried that didn't work:

```
gsub(" ", "_", data, fixed = TRUE)
gsub('[.]', '_', data)
gsub('\\.', '_', data)
```

Comment: `gsub()` is not designed to work directly on data frames.  You may need to iterate over your columns instead.  You will receive better help if you provide an example of what your data looks like and what you want to achieve. Use `dput(head(data))` and copy and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Ohhh I see! I just realized that when I skipped the first 43 rows, the column names automatically added .'s instead of spaces so I needed to gsub with colnames(data) instead and replace the periods with _'s! Thank you so much for your help & advice on how to ask questions in the future :)

Comment: is it just in the colnames that you want spaces as underscores, not the actual values in the data.frame? If so might be better to do: data <- read.csv("file.csv",check.names=FALSE); colnames(data) <- gsub(" ","_",colnames(data))

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `read.csv`, I think you're working on the *values* and not the column names. (I say this mostly because `read.csv` will not allow column names with spaces, by default.)

A quick hack to change all string columns as you want would be

```r
data <- read.csv("path to csv", skip = 43)
ischr <- sapply(data, is.character)
data[,ischr] <- lapply(data[,ischr,drop=FALSE], gsub, pattern = " ", replacement = "_")
```

FYI, if you intend to do all columns (and not a subset as I'm doing above), then instead do

```r
data[] <- lapply(data, gsub, pattern = " ", replacement = "_")
```

If you mistakenly do `data <- lapply(..)`, it's not a huge problem, but `data` here would then be a `list`, after which you'd need to call `data <- as.data.frame(data)`, so no loss of information. The reason that `data[] <- lapply(..)` avoids this is that `lapply(.)` always returns a `list`, and `data <-` will overwrite `data` with this new `list`, discarding the `"data.frame"` class attribute. Using `data[] <-` replaces the *contents* of `data` without changing its attributes (as much), so the original class is retained.